# How to add boto library to an python-based AWS lambda function?

Tags: aws-lambda

I want to create a lambda function in python3.7 that it will use `boto` to perform some AWS query.

[image]

The function is very simple. I added `import boto` to the simple vanilla template to try out how to enable `boto`.

```
import json

import boto

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

Needless to say, it fails:

```
Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'boto'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"
}
```

So how can I add `boto` to my code?

I have checked out Layers and it is empty.

[image]

I think I can create on by uploading a zip file. But what should I put inside the zip file? What sort of directory structure is Lambda expecting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

boto has been deprecated. You should be using boto3.

Import boto3

Answer (score 1):

This is like adding additional dependencies to aws lambda.

Please follow [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html) to add boto package.